# jQuery: Dynamic Elements with Timers to fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a basic message system on my site that will queue/append messages into a div that floats at top of page. Each message should fade out after X amount of seconds but if you hover over that message is will pause it's fade out time, then on mouseleave it should resume.

So I'm trying to append a div and attach a timer to it to fade out, but upon mouseneter it will pause that fade out and upon mouseleave it will resume it. Also there is a close button that will instantly make it disappear.

I've tried `delay()` but there is no way to control it and I cannot seem to wrap my head around using `setTimeout()` to do it because I can't figure how to attach the timer to that div created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the timer ids to an object in the global scope, like `window.timers`, and on mouseover, you iterate over all the active timers, `clearTimeout()` on them and save a `timeRemaining` value - which is difference from the DOM ready timestamp and that mouseover event's timestamp. On mouseout, you set all the timers again with the `timeRemaining` value instead of the initial time value.